# how to configure php curl_init function

Tags: php

How exactly do I initiate curl_init function?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: basically use protocols to communicate to a server.  https specifically

Comment: @dave: so describe all your task in the question then.

Comment: basically using authorize.net test server to test my ecommerce website's transactions.

Comment: oh, come on, get all your minds and write the expectations **IN QUESTION**. There is the edit link there.

Comment: @Dave - This is a forum for professionals, where you have many experienced professionals offering to help. Be courteous, and do not curse at people.

Comment: @Dave This very much goes both ways. If you want help, give us enough information to know what we're supposed to help you with. Nobody particularly enjoys pulling each little bit of information out of your nose one by one, but if nobody did it, you'd get no response at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php

Any other questions?